# Mass Copy Excel Sheet from many sources

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have 2 folder, one source folder and one destination folder. 
I want copy the sheet in position 1 form every excel source file, located in source folder, in corrispective destination excel file, located in destination folder.
To make it easier, the files have the same name, simply are in different folder.

I wrote the script below that works just for a single source and destination file. The script copy position 1 sheet from source to destination and rename it.

```
Sub MassCopy()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim SheetName
    Dim Position
    Dim SourceFile, DestinationFile
    SheetName = "test_sheet"
    Position = 1
    SourceFile = "test1.xlsx"
    DestinationFile = "test2.xlsx"
    Windows(SourceFile).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks(DestinationFile).Sheets(Position)
    Set wsNew = Sheets(Sheets(Position).Index + 1)
    wsNew.Name = SheetName

End Sub
```

Is it possible to make it work for every file in source/destination folder?

Comment: Yes. Search for "loop through files in folders+VBA".

Comment: I have found example that use Dir but i've read that is suitable to work with just one directory. In fact there is a problem if i use in same macro one Dir to open source folder and another one for the target

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with a combination of of using LOOP and DIR.  Below is the template that I use when I need to loop through a file folder and repeat the same action.  Replace myPath with the file path to your folder and insert the code you want to run where I've indicated that you should enter your code.

```
Sub LoopThroughAllFiles()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  myPath = "C:\YourPath\TestFolder\"

  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

    'Do your tasks
    Enter the code for the tasks you want to accomplish here.


'Save and Close Workbook
 wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
  Loop

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This Works just for one source directory. What about for a source and a target directory? Here the code I tried to use using your example: https://pastebin.com/8QQPxz8b